# imagemagick issue converting pdf form and overlaying pages

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using imagemagik to convert pdf's ( and other types ) to jpg.

Here is my command

```
"D:\\bc_458.pdf -resize 100x100 -flatten -quality 92 -background white  D:\\tn_abc_458.jpg"
```

I am having 2 issues with this.

1) it doesn't work with pdf's that contains forms.

2) it is overlaying pages on top of each other. For example "bc_458.pdf" has 3 pages. tn_abc_458.jpg is created with all 3 layers overlaying each other.

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using? (Run `convert -version` to find out...)

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is a (pixel) images processing software.

It doesn't process PDF input files itself -- it uses Ghostscript as a *'delegate'* to convert PDF pages to pixel images first.

1. So, which version of Ghostscript have you installed? On Windows, run

   ```
   gswin32c.exe -v
   ```

   or

   ```
   gswin64c.exe -v
   ```

   on Mac OS X, Linux or Unix run:

   ```
   gs -v
   ```

   to find out.

   What exactly are you problems with the PDF forms? *'It doesn't work with forms'* doesn't tell me much...
2. The problem of overlaying the 3 page images over each other you can easily overcome: simply drop the `-flatten` part of the commandline (because that's what's responsible for the effect you observe). Furthermore, you could specify `%04d` as part of the output filename in order to have control of where ImageMagick puts the page number:

   ```
   convert \
        bc_458.pdf \
       -resize 100x100 \
       -quality 92 \
       -background white \
        page_%04d_bc_458.jpg"
   ```
3. I'm pretty sure that the command you quoted doesn't even do what you say it does:  you forgot to put the `convert` command to the front of the line.   ;-)